# Prolog problem! 'singles' !

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog homework, which should work like this:

```
  singles([1,2,3,2,2,4,1], [3,4]).
  true
```

Now I've figured out I should test if one element is single in the list then put all the single element together..then I wrote down:

```
singles(L,SL):-findall(X,isSingle(X,L),SL).
isSingle(X,L):-member(X,L),append(Y,[X|Z],L),not(member(X,L1)),append(Y,Z,L1).
```

in the `isSingle` function the `X` should be in List `L` but not in the new List `L1` without `X`, like `1` is in `[2,1,3]` but not in `[2,3]`, but sadly the whole thing doesn't work like I thought :(

I think the problem is in the `isSingle` part, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of `not(member(X,L1))` and `append(Y,Z,L1)` and your code works. I'm no Prolog expert, so I'm not entirely sure about this, but, going through the trace, it seems to have to do with the subtleties of using `not`. You're forcing the evaluation of `member` on `L1` before it has been unified in `append(Y,Z,L1)` bit.

Comment: oh thanks!! I've figured this out just now by myself! the order matters! And your explanation is perfect, totally solved my confusion, thanks again:)

Comment: @bearzk you could also use select/3 if you are allowed: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3

Answer (score 1):

```
singles(List,SelectList) :-
        singles(List,List,SelectList).

singles([],List,[]).
singles([A|R1],List,[A|R2]) :-
        unique(A,List),
        singles(R1,List,R2).
singles([A|R1],List,R2) :-
        \+(unique(A,List)),
        singles(R1,List,R2).

unique(A,List) :-
        append(L0,[A|R],List),
        \+(append(_,[A|_],L0)),
        \+(append(_,[A|_],R)).
```